Issue when creating distributable for compose desktop with ProGuard enabled
I am working on a personal Compose Desktop project, and I want to enable ProGuard's code obfuscation feature. I found a tutorial on JetBrains' GitHub page, and I altered build.gradle.kts file to following:
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    alias(libs.plugins.composeCompiler)
}

kotlin {
    jvm("desktop")

    sourceSets {
        val desktopMain by getting

        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material3)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
        }
        desktopMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
        }
    }
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "com.dangxuanthong.composedesktopproguard"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }

        buildTypes.release.proguard {
            version = "7.5.0"
            obfuscate.set(true)
        }
    }
}

I executed the command ./gradlew createReleaseDistributable to create an obfuscated .msi file but there was some errors. Here is the error log:
Type-safe project accessors is an incubating feature.
 
> Task :composeApp:proguardReleaseJars
ProGuard, version 7.5.0
Note: duplicate definition of resource file [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]
... (37 duplicate lines)

Note: there were 37 duplicate class definitions.
      (https://www.guardsquare.com/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#duplicateclass)
Note: androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache calls 'Method.getAnnotation'                                                                                                  
Note: androidx.compose.ui.text.platform.ReflectionUtil$findAssignableField$result$1 calls 'Field.getType'
Warning: kotlinx.datetime.serializers.DateBasedDateTimeUnitSerializer: can't find superclass or interface kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractPolymorphicSerializer
Warning: kotlinx.datetime.serializers.DatePeriodComponentSerializer: can't find superclass or interface kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer
Warning: kotlinx.datetime.serializers.DatePeriodIso8601Serializer: can't find superclass or interface kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer
... (834 more lines warning about can't find superclass...)

Note: androidx.compose.ui.text.platform.AwtFontUtils: can't find dynamically referenced class sun.font.CFont
Note: androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.internal.JvmViewModelProviders accesses a declared constructor '<init>()' dynamically
Warning: there were 886 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (https://www.guardsquare.com/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#unresolvedclass)
Unexpected error
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
        at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:526) ~[proguard-base-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
        at proguard.pass.PassRunner.run(PassRunner.java:24) ~[proguard-base-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
        at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:353) ~[proguard-base-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
        at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:142) ~[proguard-base-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
        at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:648) ~[proguard-base-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
 
> Task :composeApp:proguardReleaseJars FAILED
 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':composeApp:proguardReleaseJars'.
> External tool execution failed:
  * Command: [C:\DevTools\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe, -cp, "C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.guardsquare\\proguard-gradle\\7.5.0\\6c4d00000430
5c38e553c4f86e8363b2f58fdc09\\proguard-gradle-7.5.0.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.github.zafarkhaja\\java-semver\\0.9.0\\59a83ca73c72
a5e25b3f0b1bb305230a11000329\\java-semver-0.9.0.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.guardsquare\\proguard-base\\7.5.0\\54c972019119fa982868
5cc7f67e0a3f60122004\\proguard-base-7.5.0.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.guardsquare\\proguard-core\\9.1.4\\7854df8df0701222ae56be7677
74de6f74687cdd\\proguard-core-9.1.4.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.jetbrains.kotlin\\kotlin-metadata-jvm\\2.0.0\\48228e400bdde2de1bb5a
f4e91373387b327b84c\\kotlin-metadata-jvm-2.0.0.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.jetbrains.kotlin\\kotlin-stdlib\\2.0.0\\b48df2c4aede9586
cc931ead433bc02d6fd7879e\\kotlin-stdlib-2.0.0.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.google.code.gson\\gson\\2.9.0\\8a1167e089096758b49f9b3406
6ef98b2f4b37aa\\gson-2.9.0.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.apache.logging.log4j\\log4j-core\\2.19.0\\3b6eeb4de4c49c0fe38a4ee27188ff5fee
44d0bb\\log4j-core-2.19.0.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.apache.logging.log4j\\log4j-api\\2.19.0\\ea1b37f38c327596b216542bc636cfdc0b80
36fa\\log4j-api-2.19.0.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.json\\json\\20231013\\e22e0c040fe16f04ffdb85d851d77b07fc05ea52\\json-20231013.ja
r;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.jetbrains\\annotations\\24.0.0\\69b8b443c437fdeefa8d20c18d257b94836a92b9\\annotations-24.0.0.jar", proguard.ProGuard, -include, "D:\\LapTrinh\\Kotlin\\Compose Desktop With Proguard\\composeApp\\build\\compose\\tmp\\proguardReleaseJars\\root-config.pro"]
  * Working dir: []
  * Exit code: 1
  * Standard output log: D:\LapTrinh\Kotlin\Compose Desktop With Proguard\composeApp\build\compose\logs\proguardReleaseJars\java-2024-07-21-16-19-54-out.txt
  * Error log: D:\LapTrinh\Kotlin\Compose Desktop With Proguard\composeApp\build\compose\logs\proguardReleaseJars\java-2024-07-21-16-19-54-err.txt
 
 
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
 
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
 
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
 
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
 
BUILD FAILED in 21s
13 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 8 up-to-date

I had to cut out some passages because the log was 984 lines long. Full log can be found here.
It warned about cannot find class kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer although I didn't use anything related to kotlinx-datetime or kotlinx-serialization library.
Here is the link to my GitHub project repository

i just disabled the proguard to get release build :(
hope it'll get fixed in future updates

Create a rules.pro file besides your app build.gradle(.kts) file and add the following in it:
-dontwarn kotlinx.datetime.**
# other things...

In your build script, specify that file as a proguard configuration file:
buildTypes.release.proguard {
    configurationFiles.from("rules.pro")
    // other things...
}

Note that it may be better to NOT obfuscate the code.
For some example Compose Desktop apps with various proguard rules see these:

Cutcon
Kotlin Explorer
ImageViewer


But I can still enable code optimization, right? I just want to remove unnecessary code to reduce executable file

Yes you can optimize by setting optimize.set(true) in buildTypes.release.proguard { or comment/delete -dontoptimize line in your rules.pro file if you have specified it previously.

If your result optimized app breaks or does not work as expected, probably Proguard has mistakenly optimized (deleted) one or more classes of your libraries. In that case, either disable the optimization altogether by adding -dontoptimize in your rules.pro or add proper rules in the rules.pro for that library. See example links in the answer.
